# Assert type alias is not never?

Tags: typescript

I have a type alias that's not derived from a value. Something as simple as `type t0 = never`. I have hundreds of these aliases (they're generated from an external source) and should never be never.

How do I assert to typescript that type t0 should not be never?

I've found

```js
type t0 = never;
// throws
let _notNever0: t0 = 0 as any;
```

will fail, but I'd like something shorter, something I can reuse.

Unfortunately, the below does not throw in TypeScript

```js
function NotNever<T>() {
  let _: T = 0 as any;
}
type t0 = never;
// doesn't throw
NotNever<t0>();
```

Comment: CHeck [this](https://tsplay.dev/wg6p4W)

Comment: Yeah I think you'll need something of the [form](https://tsplay.dev/WYBogw) `Assert<NotNever<t0>>` instead of `AssertNotNever<t0>`.  If you tried to write `type AssertNotNever<T extends XXX> = ...` then no matter what `XXX` is, you'll find that `never` extends it, so no compiler error will happen.  Too bad there are no "invalid" types as asked for in [ms/TS#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689).

Comment: @captain-yossarian That's much closer to what I was looking for!

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, a throw type would make what I'm trying to do waaaay easier.

Comment: @Coburn here https://catchts.com/type-negation you can find my article about type negation in typescript with some examples